# Windows mouse coordinates VS OpenGL mouse coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl, mouse-coordinates

How can I determine(this isn't the right term to use I know) that, for **every** position of mouse in a `window space`, it gets converted to `OGL space`(-1, 1). In this case, the user moves the mouse very fast, that I assume **all** of its previous positions are converted into OGL coordinates. What I am trying to say is that...is a common CPU fast enough to do that (to track all previous events) even if my `C++ OGL coordinates converter` is very computational expensive? lets say I put very time consuming loops in there? or.. very fast `method()`. How can I assure that no OGL coordinates are skipped out if I move the mouse fast enough?
I'm not jumping to any conclusion here or assuming something else might you think.

**Edit:**

My program main loop is like this(pseudocode):

```
void Pollevents()
{
    for everyt_obj in this
    {
        if Not Collide()
        {

            Move(x, y) //

        }
    }
}

void MousePos()
{
    mouse.pos = To_OGL_Coord2f()
}
```

These are separate threads to be executed (But not actually a real thread)
Suppose `mouse.pos = (0, 0)` then I moved the mouse fast enough to make the new `mouse.pos` to (10, 10). In a single execution of a loop, the mouse position changed very far from where it was before. Now, how can I tell to my program, by implementing `Bresenham's line algorithm` as mentioned by Christian Rau, that those values generated by that algorithm(not being tracked) have been crossed by the mouse. Will I add another loop for that to step for all those positions?

Comment: If your computer was considered slow *13 years ago*, it would still be capable of performing over 100 *million* computations per second. Is there something about turning one pair of numbers into another pair that makes you think your computer would be unable to handle it?

Comment: I mean, the program currently running. Not the OS being computed by the processor. Take a look at [this](http://s23.postimg.org/uoyhevx2z/pos.png)

Comment: @NicolBolas you can see the very big difference of mouse positions in the link I have given as I hover the mouse in the window. Not unless this is an issue of printing it to bash

Comment: @mr5: Could you please show us your GLFW event processing source code? Nicol Bolas is right that even ancient computers are fast enough for simething as simple as processing two integers into two floats even a million times a second, no matter which code it is actually executing. Note that what you see may simply be an artifact if your mouse's input resolution can't keep up with the speed you're actually moving it (special mice for gamers exist for a reason).

Comment: @datenwolf I think you didn't get what I am trying to tell here. This is like `As I move this mouse, every window coordinates it has been moved to will be converted to OGL coordinates and keep track of all of its previous *footprint*` as if no positions will be skipped out, as seen in the link image I give to Nicol, there has been very big difference on the printed coordinates or is this only a matter of the printing into bash. Please don't hate

Comment: @mr5: So essentially you want to store the path the mouse pointer took within the window. Well, just use a std::vector to which you append elements of `struct{float x, y; int timestamp};`. You'll have the mouse for a very long time to produce even just a MB of data. At a update rate of 60 Hz, and a struct size of 12 bytes it would take 25 minutes to grow the log to a MB. You can use this log to interpolate the positions inbetween. Most interactive applications actually keep a (short) log of mouse moves and use it to smooth out the movement in exactly that way.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I assure that no OGL coordinates are skipped out if I move the
>   mouse fast enough?

That's not possible, since there is no way to let the OS generate mouse events for each and every point a mouse move would have crossed when tracked with theoretically infinite precision.

The only way to ensure this is to fill the missing points between the two (possibly far away) mouse positions yourself. If you just want to draw a point for each position the mosue moved over (maybe using OpenGL), draw a line instead.

If you on the other hand need those intermediary mouse positions yourself for further computations, you won't get around computing them yourself using some common line rasterization algorithm (like the [*Bresenham Algorithm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm), *the* school book algorithm for line rasterization). What this basically does is compute each point on a discrete grid that a line from one point to another would have crossed (similar to what your graphics card does when converting a line into discrete pixels), so this will generate each discrete mouse position your virtual mouse path has crossed (ignoring any non-linear mouse movement between measurement points).

**EDIT:** If you don't need a discrete line with proper equal-width characteristics a much easier way than messing with line rasterization would also be to just work with floating point positions and do a simple linear interpolation of the end points, like *datenwolf* writes in his comment. This will also give you a better timing precision than discrete mouse positions. But it all depends on what you actually want to do with those mouse positions (and now would be a good way to tell us).

**EDIT:** From your updated question it looks like you need the mouse positions at a high granularity in order to compute the collision of the mouse with some objects. In this case you don't actually need the intermediary points at all. Just take the line from the current mouse position to the previous one (represented as just a pair of points, or whatever theoretical line representation) and compute the collision of the objects with that line instead of the individual points.

Comment: For a specified amount of time, how can I do this? let's say in a milli second. Ahm, I mean my program is event-driven mostly by mouse. How could I tell to my program that this position had been crossed by the mouse. Also, please note that this is not just a single flush to execute.

Comment: @mr5 Nothing with time (if you don't need some specific timing yourself). If you get a mouse event just compute all the points between the mouse position you get and the mouse position of the last event (that you stored somewhere). If you are talking about generating virtual mouse events yourself for those intermdiary points, then I don't think that's particularly good idea.

Comment: @mr5 What is it you want to do with those points anyway? If you just want to do some specific computation with each and every mouse point, then just wait for ordinary move events, compute the (possibly multiple) intermediary points for each event to the last tracked position (from the last event) and invoke the computation for each of those computed points. Who says you need the actual events to occur at the granularity of individual points? If it is something more advanced you need to do with those points, then maybe it can be restructured to not even need the intermediary points at all?